# C# changing "visible" destroys the order of my docked panels?

Tags: c#, panel

I have a problem with docking. Here is the thing. I hope I can explain it well.

The design of the form is like this

```
The form
   panelA -docked on top (there is a groupbox in this, it is also docked on top)
   panelB -docked on top
   tablist -docked fill
```

The thing is, panelB needs to be in the middle. The visibility of panelB is controlled by a combobox in panelA. So, when the user selects anything in combobox(in panelA), the panelB is visible and loaded with the associated user control.

The Document Outline is

```
The form
  tablist
  panelB
  panelA
```

They are on the same level but not the same order with the design. I don't know why.

The problem is, I make panelB visible=false in constructor, and make it visible again in combobox_selectedIndexChanged. But the panelB appears to be on top of panelA. After making it visible, this is how it looks;

```
the form
  panelB
  panelA
  tablist
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sequence after making panelB visible to `true`:

```
panelA.BringToFront();
panelB.SendToBack();
```

Comment: it is still the same. Also the tablist disappeared

Comment: The idea is you'll have to play with those methods

Comment: thank you. If i can't fix this, i will do the workaround by changing the height only.